# TDD Unit test of ASP.NET Webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, mocking, tdd

I am new to TDD and I am reading many books to grasp the concepts of TDD.

I have few question if someone can guide me. Let's say If I am creating a unit test for login authentication, Do I have to insert a dummy User first and then test the methods based on the test user I have inserted?

In order to test the business logic for Login Authentication, here are some test methods that I have in my mind:

```
1- Authenticate_UserId_or_Password_ShouldNotbeNull()

2- Authenticate_UserId_And_Password_ShouldreturnValidUser()
```

For #1, I created a test method:

```
[Test]
public void Authenticate_UserId_or_Password_ShouldNotbeNull()
{

LoginService login = new LoginService();
string strUserId="UserIdTest";
string strPassword="PasswordTest";

login.Authenticate(strUserId, strPassword);

// What assert method should I use to test it? 

}
```

Also one more question, I was reading about mocking. Is mocking another name of Proxy Pattern?

Comment: In case number of one you don't need to mock, in case number 2 I think you need to. But it depends. Could you provide the method to test? For example if you are using the `Membership` class (as often used in the ASP.NET account controller) it is very hard to testing it (since it is static). If so I would recommend to start on a different point :-)

Comment: Well I am not using a Membership Class. I have my own custom login system. Could you please provide me the detail answer for number 1. how can I create a Unit test for Authenticate_UserId_or_Password_ShouldNotbeNull()

Comment: Thanks John for improving the question.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you would not want to use TDD on the user interface. If you keep a clean separation between the UI and business logic, then you can more easily test the business logic, which is the part that will more likely break.

Other testing techniques can be used to test the user interface, though that is *still* not very amenable to TDD.

Comment: I am not using TDD on UI layer. I am trying to create a Business logic layer through TDD technique. Also it's a webform application. I know without TDD I can implement it easily.

Comment: But you see, in this case, you didn't need to specify that you were working on a Web Forms project, or even that it is ASP.NET. Business logic should be independent of whether you're using ASP.NET or not. By including the fact that it is ASP.NET, you made the readers believe that it _mattered_ that it is ASP.NET.

Comment: I agree and really thanks for your help so far. Let me edit the question further.